# how to use tap and map in angular

Tags: angular, dictionary

I get a url from backend which i want to redirect to  from my angular project but not sure how to go about it.

```
 public createPaymentMethod(paymentMethodDto: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(ConfigService.Configuration.apiUrl + `/payments`, paymentMethodDto)
            .pipe(
                tap((result: TpayData) => console.log(result)),
// in the result log i have a field with name 3durl and clientAUth etc
                map(res => res._3dsUrl ),
                tap(_3dUrl => console.log(_3dUrl))
            );
    }

async addPaymentMethod(): Promise<void> {
        const encrypted = this.encrypt();
        this.paymentForm.controls['creditCard'].setValue(encrypted);
        const loader = await this.loaderService.showLoader();
        this.paymentApiService.createPaymentMethod(this.paymentForm.value)
            .subscribe((payment) => {
                console.log("expect" + payment)
                    this.close(payment);
                    this.loaderService.successMessage();
                },
                (error) => this.loaderService.errorApiMessage(error)
            );
        await loader.dismiss();
    }
```

What i want to check is if the 3duRl is not null then redirect to this url, if it is null then the other values from the returned response i will handle. currently im not sure how to bring the url into the async addPaymentMethod and redirect to it if its available

Comment: ok i will correct that thanks

Comment: @R.Richards did you understand my question ? i want to get the value from the result and also check if not null and use it to redirect

Comment: what are you not able to achieve ? your console.log("expect" + payment) inside addPaymentMethod() must be giving you the url.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor please import the Router service provided by Angular:

```
private router: Router
```

Then:

```
async addPaymentMethod(): Promise<void> {
        const encrypted = this.encrypt();
        this.paymentForm.controls['creditCard'].setValue(encrypted);
        const loader = await this.loaderService.showLoader();
        this.paymentApiService.createPaymentMethod(this.paymentForm.value)
            .subscribe((payment) => {
                  If(payment) { 
                     this.router.navigateByUrl(payment)
                     console.log("expect" + payment)
                     this.close(payment);
                     this.loaderService.successMessage();
                  }
               },
                (error) => this.loaderService.errorApiMessage(error)
            );
         await loader.dismiss();
    }
```